# Limiting Distribution of what was Chi square

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Z_n\sim \chi^2(n)$ and $W_n= Z_n/n^2$. Find the limiting distribution of $W_n$.

Using the delta method seems a bit unusual, since the function in question would be $g(z) = z/n^2$. Thus, I attempted to find the mgf of $W_n$. I know that $M_Z(t) = (1-2t)^{-n/2}$, so I can find 
$$M_W(t) = E[e^{Wt}] = E[e^{tZ/n^2}] = E[e^{1/n}e^{tZ/n}] = e^{1/n}M_Z(t/n) = e^{1/n}(1-2t/n)^{-n/2}.$$
Now I need to take the limit as $n\to\infty$. But the first factor goes to 1, and the second (I think) goes to $e^{(-2t)\cdot(-1/2)} = e^t$. I don't recognize this as any familiar mgf. What is my mistake? Is there a better way to do this problem?

Comment: $M_{W_n}(t) = M_{Z_n}(t/n^2)$

Comment: Then $M_W(t) = M_Z(t/n^2) = (1-2t/n^2)^{-n/2} = (1-d(n)/n)^{-n/2}$ where $d(n)=2t/n$, which tends to zero as $n\to\infty$. Thus, the limit is $e^{0(-1/2)} = 1$, which I still don't recognize.

Comment: 1 is the mgf or the characteristic function of the point distribution $\delta(x)$ (i.e. $p(X > 0) = 1$, $p(X < 0)=0$)

Comment: Aha, so it is degenerate at 0. Thank you so much.

Comment: you can also see it from the variance of $\chi^2(n)$ which is $2n$ and its mean-value which is $n$, so $\mathbb{E}(W_n) =\mathbb{E}(Z_n)/n^2 = 1/n$ and $\mathbb{E}((W_n-1/n)^2) = \mathbb{E}((Z_n-n)^2)/n^4= 2/n^3$ thus proving that  $W_n$'s mean and variance $\to 0$ i.e. that the limit is the point distribution $\delta(x)$